# Having two datacenters with two virtual servers at each, what is the suitable redis topology for high availability?

Tags: redis, failovercluster, redis-sentinel

I have two data centers, A and B, which has two virtual servers at each site. We have connectivity between the two sites. I'm planning to deploy one redis HA cluster with two masters and two slaves. One master, one slave on A and vice-versa at the other site.

Will it work in a disaster situation where a data center is not available? Redis recommendation is to have a 3 master server cluster. I'm confused with the concept and actually how the topology should be in this  scenario. If I need more servers, how should the redis cluster be configured to handle disaster situation of loss of one site?